# Вывод файлов c возможностью скачки на Yii2

Tags: yii2

Доброго времени суток! Не могу реализовать вывод файлов с возможностью скачки, ссылки вывожу так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Может кто знает расширение или виджет в котором файлы типа PDF выводились вместе со значком PDF и их можно было скачать?

Comment: в чем проблема добавить значок на CSS ?

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский я думал может расширения на Yii2 есть.  Допустим я добавлю значок на Css но при этом не будет возможности скачать , а хотелось бы чтобы была возможность скачать

Comment: Как значок на css связан с возможностью скачать по ссылке?

Comment: Тем что я хочу добавить возможность скачать pdf или word файлы а они сейчас выводятся только как ссылки. Я могу заменить ссылки значками pdf или word

Comment: Остается только добавить возможность скачать